# using `i18next.t` from inside my angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, i18next

I'm using the library `i18ng` from https://github.com/mikefrey/i18ng

I need to access the translation function from within a controller though, I can't seem to figure out how this is exposed.

I see the library saves a reference from `window.i18n` but it doesn't seem to return anything for me.

I've tried this in my controller:

```
    var t = window.i18n.t;
    $rootScope.pageTitle = t('test'); //should produce "this is a test"
```

But all I get is an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since t is a filter, you should be able to use

```
$rootScope.pageTitle = $filter('t')('test');
```

where `t` is the name of the filter provided by i18ng library and `$filter` is the angular filter service injected into  your factory/service.

It does feel kind of hacky and its unfortunate that the author hasnt provided a service. Given how little activity it has seen recently, I would shy away from using it and use something like [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) instead

**UPDATE:** doh, the author does provide an injectable service and its right there in his [README.md](https://github.com/mikefrey/i18ng/blob/master/README.md):

```
angular.module('myModule')
.controller('myCtrlr', function($scope, i18ng) {
  $scope.translatedText = i18ng.t('somekey')
}])
```

Comment: that worked. thanks. I like this one because its based off i18next which can be used just about everywhere. That other project seems to define everything in angular space which doesn't sound too good to me.

Comment: fyi: i had to inject `$filter` to use this and you're missing a  closing `'`

Comment: Apparently there is a documented service in this library. Ive updated my answer